# i need a text input area for a form to appear only if 'other' is selected on drop down select list?

Tags: javascript, html

Well my question is pretty simple and straight forward.
The html for the drop down list is easy enough
here is the script and html that i found to use

```
<select id='combo'>
<option>Yes</option>
<option>No</option>
<option>other</option>
</select>
<input  id='text1' style='display: none'/>
<input  id='text2' style='display: none'/>

<script>

document.getElementById('combo').onchange = function() {
var display = this.selectedIndex == 2 ? "inline" : "none";
document.getElementById('text1').style.display = display;
document.getElementById('text2').style.display = display;
}
</script>
```

how do i go about applying this?
if of course, this even works...

thanks

Comment: What do you mean "how do i go about applying this?"? Looks obvious to me. Please explain what you don't understand.

Comment: What are you asking? This works fine as is http://jsfiddle.net/J9rXS/

Comment: It works... what do you mean by 'applying' this? Like, how to create an HTML page and just put this markup and script in there and try it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the event after the DOM is loaded.

```
window.onload = function()
{
    document.getElementById('combo').onchange = function() {
        var display = this.selectedIndex == 2 ? "inline" : "none";
        document.getElementById('text1').style.display = display;
        document.getElementById('text2').style.display = display;
    }
}
```

or

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event)
{
    document.getElementById('combo').onchange = function() 
    {
        var display = this.selectedIndex == 2 ? "inline" : "none";
        document.getElementById('text1').style.display = display;
        document.getElementById('text2').style.display = display;
    }
});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/DOMContentLoaded

http://jsfiddle.net/J9rXS/1/

Notice how I removed the OnLoad option from jsFiddle, which adds a wrap in the header (thus it is working for the guys in the comments above).

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait till the DOM is loaded. If you dont wait untill it is loaded, `document.getElementById('combo')` will not return annything and therfore you will not bind the event.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){

  document.getElementById('combo').onchange = function() {
    var display = this.selectedIndex == 2 ? "inline" : "none";
    document.getElementById('text1').style.display = display;
    document.getElementById('text2').style.display = display;
  }

},false);
```